# Unable to override actionPerformed (using ANONYMOUS class) upon compilation. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, event-handling

Already looked through 3 questions posted earlier on the same issue but could not figure out where am I going wrong.
I'm trying to implement ActionListener for a button (b) as-

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int first= Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
            int second= Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
            int result= first+second;
            tf3.setText(Integer.toString(result));
        }
```

Upon compilation, this gives a msg as-

***MyFrame.java:3: error: MyFrame is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
class MyFrame extends Frame implements ActionListener
^
1 error***

Full Code Snippet :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class MyFrame extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    TextField tf1;
    TextField tf2;
    TextField tf3;
    Button b;
    Panel p;
    MyFrame()
    {
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        p = new Panel();
        tf1 = new TextField(10);
        tf2 = new TextField(10);
        tf3 = new TextField(10);
        b = new Button("+");
        p.add(tf1);
        p.add(tf2);
        p.add(tf3);
        p.add(b);
        add(p);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int first= Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
                int second= Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
                int result= first+second;
                tf3.setText(Integer.toString(result));
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing `ActionListener` in an anonymous class instance, but you also declare that `MyFrame` implements `ActionListener`, which it doesn't.

If you want `MyFrame` to implement `ActionListener` directly, move `actionPerformed` to be a method of that class. If not, remove `implements ActionListener` from `MyFrame` declaration.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot.